# GROUP BY statement with a PIVOT command in T-SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, group-by, pivot

I have a SQL query that involves a PIVOT command that creates the correct table but now I need to GROUP BY one of the columns.

When I try to add the GROUP BY statement, it is returning the following error: "Column 'PivotTable.1' is invalid in the select list because it is not contained in either an aggregate function or the GROUP BY clause."

```
SELECT [Load ID],[1],[2],[3],[4]
FROM TMS_Load_Stops
PIVOT (
    MIN([Stop Zip])
    for [Sequence] IN ([1],[2],[3],[4])
    ) PivotTable
;
```

The original code yields the below results:
[image]

And I would like the results to be as follows (values are random numbers for explanation purposes):
[image]

Comment: What you are trying to do here ?, edit the question add some sample data & desired result would helpful.

Comment: You can't group by only 1 column. Maybe a distinct? Maybe something completely different? My guess is the approach here is not quite right. But without sample data and desired output it is just guesswork.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use conditional aggregation.  It is much simpler:

```
SELECT [Load ID],
       MIN(CASE WHEN [Sequence] = 1 THEN [Stop Zip] END) as [1],
       MIN(CASE WHEN [Sequence] = 2 THEN [Stop Zip] END) as [2],
       MIN(CASE WHEN [Sequence] = 3 THEN [Stop Zip] END) as [3],
       MIN(CASE WHEN [Sequence] = 4 THEN [Stop Zip] END) as [4],
FROM TMS_Load_Stops
GROUP BY [Load ID];
```

The `PIVOT` doesn't work because you have additional columns in the table being pivoted.  I just don't like the syntax or how it works, but you can also fix it by only selecting the columns you need:

```
SELECT [Load ID], [1], [2], [3], [4]
FROM (SELECT [Load ID], [Sequence], [Stop Zip]
      FROM TMS_Load_Stops
     ) ls
PIVOT (
    MIN([Stop Zip])
    for [Sequence] IN ([1],[2],[3],[4])
    ) PivotTable
;
```

Comment: Thank you! The results are exactly what I was looking for

Comment: Using a conditional here is computationally intensive and will drain resources. It works for quick 1-off analyses on small dataframes; but the optimum method is the PIVOT. 

You use 'Group by' to define the key on which to aggregate on. Otherwise the PIVOT is just unstacking the label-value pair into columns where each unique record gets its own row...which is fine; that's a pivot. Add a 'GROUP BY' clause with your key(s) and you're much better off than using 'CASE WHEN'.

You'll also need to specify the aggregation method on the field and give it an alias for the GROUP BY to work.

Answer (score 3):

If you omit the Group by clause it automatically takes [Load ID] as grouping column. We have three types of columns in pivot - Grouping column, aggregating column and spanning column. Here the grouping is [Load ID], spanning is [Sequence] and aggregating is [Stop Zip].
Use the below query.

```
SELECT [Load ID],[1],[2],[3],[4]
FROM TMS_Load_Stops
PIVOT (
    MIN([Stop Zip])
    for [Sequence] IN ([1],[2],[3],[4])
    ) PivotTable
```

Answer (score 2):

You have to "project away" any additional column in `TMS_Load_Stops` before the `PIVOT` because it already performs grouping - using all columns not mentioned in the `PIVOT`:

```
SELECT [Load ID],[1],[2],[3],[4]
FROM (select [Load ID],[Sequence],[Stop Zip] from TMS_Load_Stops) t
PIVOT (
    MIN([Stop Zip])
    for [Sequence] IN ([1],[2],[3],[4])
    ) PivotTable
;
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's an example of specifying the aggregation method for each field & realiasing:

```
SELECT 
    [Load ID]
    ,sum([1]) AS [1]
    ,sum([2]) AS [2]
    ,sum([3]) AS [3]
    ,sum([4]) AS [4]
FROM (select * from TMS_Load_Stops) src
PIVOT (
    MIN([Stop Zip])
    for [Sequence] IN ([1],[2],[3],[4])
    ) PivotTable
GROUP BY [Load ID]
;
```

In lines 3-6 we've added an aggregation method 'SUM' to sum the field records upon aggregation. This way, the interpreter knows how to aggregate when grouping with 'GROUP BY'.

^ We want to steer clear of conditional 'CASE WHEN' if at all possible since its computationally expensive. PIVOT works like expected; it unstacks the field-value relationship into their own columns.

You can also reference the pivot table as a 'common table expression' by calling it again. This way the 'GROUP BY' syntax is implicit. It would look like this:

```
Select * from (
    SELECT 
        [Load ID]
        ,[1]
        ,[2]
        ,[3]
        ,[4]
    FROM (select * from TMS_Load_Stops) src
    PIVOT (
        MIN([Stop Zip])
        for [Sequence] IN ([1],[2],[3],[4])
        ) PivotTable 
) AggregatedPivot
    ;
```